# Can't convert List to ICollection - Fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, one-to-many

I've done this before, I don't know why this is throwing me errors.

These are my classes:

```
public class ChatModel
{
    public int ChatID { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ChatModel> Messages { get; set; }
}

public class MessageModel
{
    public int MessageID { get; set; }
    public string Issuer { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public ChatModel Chat { get; set; }
}
```

And this is what I'm doing through Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ChatModel>()
            .HasMany<MessageModel>(c => c.Messages)
            .WithRequired(m => m.Chat);
```

The line that's giving me errors is this one:

```
.HasMany<MessageModel>(c => c.Messages)
```

It says:

> Error CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

But honestly, I have absolutely no idea, I've done exactly the same thing with other classes while creating other relationships. But this one is giving me a headache.

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Should it not be `public virtual List<MessageModel> Messages`?

Comment: Omg yea I'm so dumb. Sorry, I gotta finish this project for the next week and I haven't slept at all. Haha thank you so much. :)

Comment: Glad to help :)